# Is my proof for a statement regarding group correct?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

> For a group of order $110$, there must be a cyclic subgroup of order $2$, $5$ or $11$.

I am not sure if the statement is correct or not.

---

My approach:

For a given group we can have a subgroup $H = \langle a\rangle$ generated by element $a\in G\space(a \neq e)$

$H$ can have order $2,5 ,11,10,22,55,$ or $110$. (By langrange's theorem)

If $H$ has order $2, 5, \text{ or } 11$. we are done.

If $H$ has order $10$ then consider subgroup of $H$ generated by $a^5 = \langle a^5\rangle$. Which will definitely have order $2$. (because $a^{10} = e \implies (a^5)^2 = e$ and if $(a^5)^k=e$ for some $k<2$ then $order(a) \neq 10$)

Similar arguments can be given for case $22, 55 , \text{ and }110$.

Comment: Hmm, to cut things short, have you come across Cauchy’s Theorem? The “or” in your statement can even be replaced by “and”...

Comment: Not yet, but I definitely will have a look at that. It seems quite interesting. :)

Comment: Then you are good to go with your reasoning, well done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct. It's good that you checked both that $a^5$ had order dividing $2$ but also could not have smaller order.